# IPv6 tunnel interface

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, tunnel

I don't know its valid question or not.My question is i have eth0 interface with public IPv4 address and i already created 6to4 tunnel for ipv6.So my question is when i am trying to access a ipv6 host or address ,the system is automatically find the 6to4 for traffic or we need to specify the particular interface  name.Suppose i am trying to access rdesktop over ipv6,we need to specify interface name?

Comment: Don't use 6to4, it's very unreliable. Use a supported tunnel like those from tunnelbroker.net. They also provide instructions on how to configure your host.

Comment: i am using for experiment purpose

Comment: just leave that 6to4 tunnel.my question is if i am using tunnel broker or teredo the ipv6 traffic automatically use that interface ,am i right

Comment: If you have a working IPv6 tunnel and the destination you are connecting to supports IPv6 then usually your connections will use IPv6

Answer (score 0):

No, what you need is just adding routing rules, if necessary.
If site-to-site tunnel(not multiSite-to multiSite)
1. different networks need routing rules;
2. Same network does not need routing rules.

Answer (score 0):

Tunnel interfaces follow exactly the same routing mechanism as regular interfaces.

- If the destination address is link-local, it needs to be specified along with the interface name.
- If the destination address is global, it doesn't even *accept* an interface name; the interface and gateway are determined according to your system's routing table.

Normally you would have a "default" route, i.e. destination `::/0`, specifying which interface to use.

```
ip route add ::/0 via ::192.88.99.1 dev 6to4tunnel
```